# updating .json file in production

Tags: php, laravel, npm, vuejs2

i am working on a project that have a scenario that multiple cascade relate models been updated by one user and then the updates were save to a json file. The other users should be able to access this dynamic json file from a vue template from the front end.

the problem I found is the front end users won't get the most updated cascade json until I recompile the asset. Should I have "npm run watch" on all the time in the production server or there should have a better way ? Thanks!

Comment: What sort of database are you using? Are you persisting the data with only this JSON file? You can use some sort of [webpush implementation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites) to allow the frontend to detect changes on the server without a full refresh

Comment: mysql.  most of data persist in the db. this is the only json file that front end needs to consume.  let me check the webpush implementation... thanks!